# Compressing large data arrays as PNG files

Tags: python, compression, png, matplotlib

As output files from a measurement I get large ASCII files, containing a 1000x1000 table of float numbers (~15MB). As those are impractical in large numbers (ie another 1000 measurements per series) I would like to effectively compress them. Exploiting the data structure (basically a 1 MP map -> picture) I tried to use pylabs imsave function to generate PNG files from the raw data, which worked nicely and yielded 200kB (!!!!!) *.png.

To analyse the data at a later point I obviously need to reverse-process the PNG and would like to get the identical initial table back. However the alleged function, imread, yields a 4-tuple , that I cannot figure out. Does anybody have any experience with such a process or have a better idea how to solve the compressing problem (simply zipping doesnt even remotely compress enough).

```
import numpy
import Image
import matplotlib
import pylab

data=numpy.genfromtxt('raw data.txt',autostrip=True, case_sensitive=True)
pylab.imsave('convert.png',data)

out=pylab.imread('convert.png')
numpy.savetxt('converted.txt', out[0], fmt='%1.4e')
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the png is so small is that it uses the zlib library. I think you would rather use that library instead of the png wrapper, it will be less confusing.

See http://zlib.net.

If you still want to use the png library, the fact that you have 4-tuples is because png images usually have an alpha channel, thus the format is RGBA and you have to use all 4 to reconstruct your data.

Comment: I can only find C versions of zlib, how do I use it with Python? Asides, if it was possible to convert back the PNG I would be happy to use that, the computing time and especially the compression rate are brilliant. Is that at all possible?

Comment: I found this, it's in the standard library: http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html.

Comment: Basically, to reconstruct from the PNG you need to take for each pixel the R, G, B, then A value next to each other for each pixel. This means you need to write: out[0][0][0], out[1][0][0], out[2][0][0], out[3][0][0], out[0][0][1], etc.

Comment: what do you mean "take the values next to each other"? add the 4 values of a tuple? I am sorry to be so needy, but I really cant find any useful information anywhere. How does the PNG encoding work altogether? Could you point me in a direction where I might be able to learn and understand more about this? The concept seems to promising to just drop it.

Comment: Suppose the input is ABCDEFG... When you encode your data, the PNG is created by taking a red, green, blue, and alpha value from the input. Thus, for the first pixel, r=A, g=B, b=C, a=D. For the second pixel, r=E, g=F, b=G, a=H, etc. When you load the png in memory, you got a three dimensional array. One of the dimensions is the X, another is the Y, and another is the channel, R, G, B, and A. You can figure our which is this dimension by printing the size of the array dimensions. For example, it can be that out[0] is for all R, out[1] for all G, out[2] for B, out[3] for all A. Do you get it?

Comment: Besides, I think you are wasting a lot if CPU usage for this conversion, whereas by using zlib you don't have to do this step.

Answer (score 0):

[imsave](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imsave) saves your array as a picture file, but can you be sure it doesn't downsample the picture? Normally, a PNG image is 8 bits per channel. It is possible that pylab imread downsamples your data, sacrificing precision.

Did you do a diff between raw_data.txt and converted.txt? An option is to use the `gzip` module or the `bz2` module. See e.g. [bz2](http://docs.python.org/library/bz2.html).

Comment: Downsampling to a limited extent, especially on resolution depth level is not a problem, since means between numerous samples will be calculated per pixel anyways.

Comment: I tried gzip, but both the time it took to compress (about 10 sec) and the compression itself (-> 4-5 MB) are not good enough.